# A node reference is empty, although the multilingual support is enabled, and the node is translated

Tags: nodes, i18n-l10n

I just created a multilingual site (English-French) using Drupal 7 with the module Internationalization 7.x-1.4.
Everything is working fine except with the module References 7.x-2.0. For instance, I created a content type "School" so that each user is affiliated to a school (User A --> School 1, User B --> School 2, etc.), meaning I simply added a node reference to "School" in the user account settings. But here is the problem: if a user chooses a school on the English version of the site it won't remember the school choice on the French version (the node reference becomes empty) and vice versa.

How do I solve this?

I did enable the multilingual support for "School" with translation.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this.

http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/multi-lingual-drupal/

Comment: Answers with just a link are not considered answers, on Stack Exchange. If you can report a summary of what said in the linked page, that would be better.

Comment: That link is not relevant to this issue. It only explains how you set up a multi language site.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a node reference can only reference content in the same language. What you need to do is provide a translation of the school node in both English and French in order for both sides to see it. Also dont forget to clear cache.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module,and the problem will be fixed.